# Python function with "Position only parameter"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn python. 
Currently learning it from python docs tutorial.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

When I tried to practice Function with position only parameter,

```
def pos_only_arg(arg, /):
     print(arg)
```

Threw this error:

`File "<stdin>", line 1
    def position_only(arg, /):`

Note: Python version is 3.7.4

Can anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new feature of python 3.8, see [what's new in python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24760732)

Comment: Thanks Tom for the reference, now I have updated Python version.

Comment: Thanks @eli-k for advise, I have updated the answer.